# Function module to delete an IDoc

Tags: abap, idoc

Is there any Function Module using which I can delete an IDoc generated in SAP system.
The FM should take IDoc number as input.

Comment: Googling for `function module delete idoc` returns this name `EDI_DOCUMENT_DELETE`.

Comment: When asking a question on stackoverflow please:
Provide details. **Share your research.**

Comment: IDocs can be deleted via archiving as detailed here: https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nwpi71/7.1/en-US/dc/6b821443d711d1893e0000e8323c4f/content.htm?no_cache=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RFC EDI_DOCUMENT_DELETE can be used to delete the IDoc number.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no specific FM to delete an IDOC, but why do you want to delete IDOC's?

SAP uses IDOC status to control IDOC's . If you don't want IDOcs to be processed you may set a status to provide that.